# How can I query for the aggregate of a categorical variable only if it has a minimum count (Oracle SQL Developer)

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, aggregate-functions

I hope I am phrasing this right.

I have a table that I want to pull from (technically, this table is a view but I will be taking all attributes in my select statement).

I want to pull from the table only if the count of a group of a categorical variable is at least three.

[image]

In the example below let's say the table name is called `Shit_to_eat` and I want to pull measures from this table such as calories and weight(g). I am going to write a query that will give me those measures aggregated to the fruit groups that have a minimum number of members

The query I am attempting is

```
SELECT DISTINCT FRUIT, VARIETY_NAME, AVG(WEIGHT),  SUM(CALORIES)  FROM SHIT_TO_EAT 
WHERE COUNT VARIETY_NAME>= 3 GROUP BY FRUIT
```

And I would expect to get statistics on apples and oranges because they each contain two members and nothing on bananas and agave because they each contain only two members.

Comment: for the best practice you should always use `HAVING` to filter on aggregated data. Just remove `WHERE` condition and add `having count(variety_name) >= 3` after GROUP BY.

Comment: @zealous having was actually the first thing I tried when we were first troubleshooting this query that still returns us Agave and Banana

Answer (score 2):

Try below way - using `having` clause

```
SELECT FRUIT, AVG(WEIGHT), SUM(CALORIES)  
FROM SHIT_TO_EAT 
GROUP BY FRUIT
having COUNT(VARIETY_NAME)>= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is your solution

```
select
 fruit, 
 AVG(weight) as avg_weight, 
 SUM(calories) as total_calories  
from shit_to_eat 
group by
    fruit
having COUNT(variety_name)>= 3
```